# Excel Formula Questions, please help me not have to work this weekend

Tags: excel, function

If this has been discussed, I apologize. My boss just gave me a last minute project that needs to be completed by Monday and I am hoping someone could help tell how to complete this in a matter of minutes, not hours. I have very basic excel knowledge unfortunately, I will try to explain the best I can but I apologize in advance if there is something I didn't include or should know.

In my spreadsheet, D1-D34 has every model # of a specific brand that my company has sold last month. On a separate website, there is a chart that lists a "reward" associated with particular model sold. I can copy and paste that list into excel. When I do that, the eligible "model's" are on D56-D975, with the price associated each are on E56-E975.

Is there any formula that I can run that will basically do all of the manual work for me so that if one of the models in D1-D34 match one of the models in D56-D975, then the "reward" associated would appear in E1-E134?

Thanks a bunch. Hopefully I can get this resolved quickly and have some sort of weekend with my family.

Comment: 1. Export excel spreadsheets as csvs, 2. use python to read in csvs and do whatever you want, 3. save new file as csv, 4. Import csv into excel

Comment: If you provide a sample spreadsheet, I can provide sample python code. There's probably a way to do it with excel macros/VBA, too.

Comment: You want a VLOOKUP. =VLOOKUP([Select the value to lookup], [Highlight all the values in the 2 columns], 2, False) good luck

Answer (score 0):

In**E1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,$D$56:$E$975,2,FALSE)
```

and copy this down thru **E34**